# Как выбрать директорию для React-приложений?

Tags: django, reactjs

Всем привет! Некоторые независимых функции нужно реализовывать с помощью `отдельных реакт-приложений`. Где их (`реакт-приложения`) обычно создают: в корневой папке, рядом с Django-проектом или внутри джанго-проекта, рядом с джанго-приложениями? Так же вопрос, `каждое Реакт-приложение` создают отдельно в определенной папке или создают общую папку и размещают их все там? Или вообще без папки, сразу?

Comment: Однозначного ответа нет. Можно в отдельную папку, можно держать папку для всех React приложений, можно внутри Django проекта. Если приложение одно и проект один, есть смысл в последнем варианте. Если приложений много и есть группа фронтендеров, скорее всего они своей репой пользоваться будут.

Comment: Мне интересно, а какой обычно способ выбирают, если в будущем присоединяется группа фронтендеров?

Comment: выбирает обычно team lead, чтобы всё было структурированно и в одном месте. Опять же, если делаете в одиночку, придерживайтесь хотя бы какой-то структуры, чтобы потом можно было скриптами всё мигрировать, если уже много чего будет. Ну или ручками, но с пониманием чего куда :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Хочу уточнить. Я выбрал способ создать внутри джанго-проекта отдельную папку, например "registration", и в ней разместить и джанго- и реакт -приложения, которые будут касаться только регистрации. И такой способ использовать для дальнейших функций. Это является правильным подходом? Меня немного смущает даже способ создания джанго-приложения: python manage.py startapp registration_django registration\django_backend

Comment: Нравится делить на модули в корне? Делайте так, главное чтобы какое-то правило и структура была. Я, например, предпочитаю придерживаться MVC или подобной модели, т.е. весь React код запихнуть в представление, а там уже помодульно делить. Это не только веб-разработки касается. Например в Flutter при соблюдении BLoC тоже подобное разделение.

Comment: P.S. забыл что в Jango MVT, но суть примерно та же. Больше на ROR ориентируюсь.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за объяснения, получается, что мой метод деления на модули не так уж и плох?)

Comment: На вкус и цвет. Повторюсь, главное чтобы не было мешанины и была структура. Как в папках windows, когда фотографии лежат в библиотеке с аудиофайлами, а документы в фотографиях. Это разгребать потом муторно, также и с структурой проекта.